# Cannot access exposed response headers from POST

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, fetch-api, response-headers

I'm having trouble accessing an exposed custom header using a Fetch POST call in an Ionic 4/Angular app. I'm sending login credentials to an API that should return a `Token` header in response.

On the server side, the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is set to expose the header I'm looking to access (`Token`), but the header does not appear in the response and also does not appear to be available when I access the `Headers` object using `response.headers.get('Token')`.

Here's the response I'm getting from the server that shows the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is set, but there is no `Token` header available:

[image]

If I try to access the headers in code to see what is available, I also don't see the `Token` header:

```
const data = {
   username: 'username',
   password: 'password'
}

const response = await fetch(url, {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
});

response.headers.forEach((header) => {
   console.log("header", header);
});
```

The above code logs:

[image]

**--- Important Caveat ---**

The `Token` header *does* appear when I attempt the same request with the same credentials in Postman. I receive the following response headers:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check with the network debugger that the header is not there?

Comment: @David, yes, the first screenshot above is the response for the specific request pulled from the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools. Is there another way to debug response headers? I haven't been able to find other options in Chrome yet.

Comment: can you ask the backend to response with * instead of token?

Comment: @Robert Just tried that, and unfortunately still no Token header being sent back.

Comment: You might want to try adding `credentials: "include"` to the fetch invocation in your frontend JavaScript code, and configure the responding server to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header. I suggest that because maybe it’s possible the browser is considering the `Token` header to be a form of credentials. I’d be a bit surprised if it were, because I don’t think `Token` is a standard header that’s recognized in any specs. But it’s worth a try.

Comment: If you try the changes suggested in my other comment, you’ll also need to change the configuration on the responding server such that it doesn’t send back the wildcard in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header but instead sends it back with an actual origin value: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`

Comment: @CortneyThomas i think the problem is that the browser doesn't make the same request as the postman, maybe there is more to the story than what we see here